# when to use BSON in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, bson

when should I use BSON instead JSON? the advantage is just storage size?

I've read that foursquare stores checking data in BSON.

is this good for small data only? is there any limitation about querying, aggregating or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using BSON instead JSON will unlikely help with MongoDb because it *already* uses BSON everywhere. MongoDb is not tied to human readable JSON.

See [Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#documents) section in documentation

> Document Format MongoDB stores documents on disk in the BSON
>   serialization format. BSON is a binary representation of JSON
>   documents, though contains more data types than does JSON. For the
>   BSON spec, see bsonspec.org. See also [BSON Types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/).
>
> The mongo JavaScript shell and the MongoDB language drivers translate
>   between BSON and the language-specific document representation.